# get all the href attributes of a web site

Tags: javascript, http, href, hyperlink

can anybody tell me a way to get all the href attributes(links) in a web site using javascript?if you could give me a code example, i will be most thankful.

Answer (score 77):

You can use [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links) to get the anchors, then just loop through grabbing the `href`, like this:

```
var arr = [], l = document.links;
for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
  arr.push(l[i].href);
}
//arr is now an array of all the href attributes from the anchors in the page
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hQ54P/), you could filter it more before the [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) call on the array if you wanted, but that's the concept for grabbing the links and looping through.

Comment: how can i get links in a web page without loading it? (basically what i want is this. a user enters a URL and i want to load all the available links inside that URL.) can you please tell me a way to achieve this

Comment: @netha - That's an entirely different question, are you talking about via AJAX, or server-side? Are you using any frameworks?

Comment: No I'm not using any frame works. i wish to do it in client site (i think server-side will put more burden on server since i wish to do some operations to that links). i just need a way to do this. i will even ready to learn a framework if it does the job. how can i achieve this?

Comment: @netha - Are the pages you're getting on your domain, or another?  If they're on another you have no choice but to do it server-side, due to security restrictions.

Comment: they are not in my domain. if there is no other way then i guess i have to do it on server-side right? do you know any way to do it from server-side?

Comment: @netha - I would ask that as a separate question, including which server platform you're on, it's an *entirely* different answer, so best to be its own SO question.

Comment: I'm using WAMP server and then i guess I'm in apachi platform

Comment: which is the input for the website that i would like to extract hrefs?

Answer (score 15):

And here is one way with `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  alert(links[i].href);
}
```

Comment: Do not execute this if a page has more link, as it will show alert for i (say 50) times

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var hrefs = [];
for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++){
  if(1/* add filtering here*/)
    hrefs.push(anchors[i].href);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>One simple way</strike> One way is to use the `document.getElementsByTagName` function. For e.g.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

**Update**

There is a far easier way. See @Nick Craver's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871358/get-all-the-href-attributes-of-a-web-site/3871370#3871370).

Comment: I would argue against saying this is the simplest :)

Comment: @Nick: Point taken. Amending to "One simple". :)