# Only run a function if on X page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this JS set up but the tabs are only on one page. So I'd like to only run the function on that page to prevent any `undefined is not a function` console errors. How can I include a conditional `if` statement to this?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
});
```

So, something like:

```
if is X page {

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    });

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178578/how-to-get-url-from-browser-adress-bar -or- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-in-web-browser

Comment: `if (typeof obj.foo != 'undefined') {
  // ..
}` which is the same as the ` isset() ' function in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that page has a specific class assigned to it, or an element that only applies to that page, you can do it.  It would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
     if ($('body').hasClass('className')) {
          $('#tabs').tabs().addClass('ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix');
     }
});
```