# how to the link number in a web page using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the index number of a link? on clicking on the link?
i have tried this code, to display the values

```
alert("i am script");
var an=[];
var href=[];
var atext=[] 
an = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0;i<an.length;i++)
{
    alert("i am inside for");
    href[i]=an[i].getAttribute("href");
    atext[i]=an[i].innerHTML;   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871358/get-all-the-href-attributes-of-a-web-site

Comment: the index number would be the `i` value.

Comment: http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery it will helpful

Answer (score 0):

**With JavaScript way:**

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
  alert('index is: '+i+' link is: '+links[i].href);
}
```

**jQuery Way:**

```
var links = $('a');
$.each(links, function(index, link){ 
  alert('index is: '+index+' link is: '+$(link).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**by javascript** use **[document.links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links)**

```
var arr = [], l = document.links;
for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
  arr.push(l[i].href);
}
```

reference  [get all the href attributes of a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871358/get-all-the-href-attributes-of-a-web-site)

Update TO get the index no

```
$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$(document).find("a").each(function(index,val){

alert("it is " + index + "  whose href is " +$(val).attr("href"));

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "on clicking on the link" right? Here you have:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Try this JavaScript:**

**Html:**

```
<div id="xx">
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 4</a>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var g = document.getElementById('xx');
for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
{ 
    (function(index){
        g.children[i].onclick = function(){
              alert(index)  ;
        }    
    })(i);

}
```