# Need help to use regex in match function of javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex for getting some pattern data and it is working fine but I need to use some part of regex from a variable but I am unable to do that please help me if somebody know how to make it.

```
var subStr = document_root.documentElement.outerHTML.match(/http(.*?Frover.fff.com.*?)\;/g);
alert(subStr[0]);
```

I get first result in alert but need to do it like this.

```
var link=rover.fff.com;
var regexpattern="/http(.*?F"+link+".*?)\;/g"
var rex=new RegExp(regexpattern);
var subStr = document_root.documentElement.outerHTML.match(regexpattern);
alert(subStr[0]);
```

I don't get anything.
Please help me.
Comment if you confuse in anything.

Comment: NB: Applying regex on HTML is in most cases a bad idea.

Comment: Please describe what the purpose is of your code: do you want to find hyperlinks? What if they appear in text, or in an attribute that is not a `href`, or in an HTML comment, ....

Comment: That close reason is really a bad one. This question should be resolved without regular expressions.

Comment: [Mozilla has an entire documentation page dedicated to regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). It's definitely a good read if you're beginner

Comment: @trincot you're correct, but the duplicate was chosen because it answers **why** the OP is having the issues they're experiencing.

Comment: @trincot Perhaps a better question such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871358/get-all-the-href-attributes-of-a-web-site would be better suited for the actual content portion of this question, but based on the title, I think Wiktor chose the correct duplicate.

Comment: these links are available in some bad format in hidden div so i need to use regex.I have no other option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you need to use a variable, you have to create a new `RegExp` object, as you've tried.

It takes two parameters. The first is a string of the pattern (without the slashes at the start and end). The second is any flags (like your `g`).

So, your pattern would be something like this:

```
var regexpattern = new RegExp('http(.*?F' + link + '.*?)\\;', 'g')
```

Note, that you have to escape any special characters in the string like you would any other string (in this case, your `\` had to be escaped to `\\` so it'll work properly).

After that, you use it the same as the `/pattern/` form. In your case, be sure to use `rex`, not `regexpattern` in your `match()` function.

(If so some reason that wasn't a literal `\` and you were escaping the semi-colon, just remove it completely, you won't need to escape a semi-colon.)