# Google Tag Manager: Send first party cookie variable into a parameter

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am having a hard time finding a way to find an element on page {click_id} and replace it with a value previously captured from a first party cookie.

I have a script on my site that generates a "click_id" value which is stored in the cookie. 
I have outbound links on my site which have a placeholder {click_id}.

```
mylink.foo/?utm_campaign={click_id}&utm_source=hello
```

On click event, I want the "click_id" value to be injected in the {click_id} placeholder.

Comment: You need to use double curly braces eg. {{click_id}}, also, make sure click_id is defined before you try to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

GTM doesn't have a built-in feature for modifying URLs, only for reading them, so you'll have to write some custom code. The flow should be as follows:

1. **Create `click_id` variable** which reads click id value from wherever it needs to
2. **Create tag**: which parses outbound links on your page and inserts `click_id` into them:

   - Get all links from page: [get all the href attributes of a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871358/get-all-the-href-attributes-of-a-web-site#answer-3871370)
   - If links are outbounds/externals: https://gist.github.com/allybee/5871749
   - Add `click_id` to outbound links: [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript#answer-487084)

**Note:** you said you `"have a script on my site that generates a "click_id" value which is stored in the cookie"`. So you have to be careful about "race conditions" (ie the GTM tag running before your script). What I advise is to move all your tagging/tracking scripts to GTM, and use [GTM tag sequencing](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6238868?hl=en) to make sure they all run following the necessary order.